# Shell execution not working

Tags: php, shell

I am using

```
print_r(shell_exec('"C:\\Program Files\\Adobe\\Reader 10.0\\Reader\\AcroRd32.exe" /t c:\\bill.pdf'));
```

for print pdf but it is not working but normal command is working on command prompt

```
"C:\\Program Files\\Adobe\\Reader 10.0\\Reader\\AcroRd32.exe" /t c:\\bill.pdf"
```

can print pdf directly by command prompt.

Any help should be appreciated.

Comment: @RoyalBg that was my mistake in posting the question syntax is right

Comment: @RoyalBg I added error_reporting(E_ALL); but nothing display as error

Answer (score 0):

As noted above. your syntax missing a closing **)**

If thats not the case, check if the shell functions are not disabled in the php.ini, search for  **disable_functions**